# Extract unicode text from XML document with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
for fileid in wordlist.fileids()[4:5]:
    url = open(fileid, 'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
    find_all = soup.find_all("speech", soup)
    soup_sub = re.sub("<.+?>", "", str(find_all))
    print fileid
    print soup_sub
```

from local xml files it gets a certain ellement. Then it subs the xml code out of it and prints a list. A snipset of that list is down here. You can see that there is allot of unicode in it. How can i get this unicode out of that list?

```
<p>\nIk heet de minister van Sociale Zaken en Werkgelegenheid van harte welkom. Er hebben zich vijf sprekers voor dit VAO aangemeld.\u200a\n, \nVoorzitter. Ik wil drie moties indienen. Dit wordt topsport voor mij.\u200a\n\nMotie\nDe Kamer,\u200a\ngehoord de beraadslaging,\u200a\noverwegende dat bedrijfsongevallen wel bij de inspectie gemeld moeten worden en beroepsziekten niet;\u200a\noverwegende dat door registratie van beroepsziekten optimaal preventief beleid gevoerd kan worden;\u200a\</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you are parsing *XML* with BeautifulSoup, do [pick the right parser for the job](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) (and have `lxml` installed). You can pass an open file object to BeautifulSoup, no need to read it all into memory before parsing:

```
with open(fileid, 'r') as xml_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'xml')
```

Next, don't use `str(find_all)`; that turns all your element objects into a single (byte) string, and you won't be able to access the original Unicode text contents anymore.

Use the [`Element.get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to extract the text from each element:

```
speech_elements = soup.find_all("speech")
speech_text = [elem.get_text() for elem in speech_elements]
```

This'll ensure that you still get the full `unicode` contents, not some `str()` conversion; you now have a list with `unicode` objects per `<speech>` element found.